# RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U on "\\?\C:" Returns Invalid Path

Tags: winapi

Why is it that when I call `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U` on the path `\\?\C:`, instead of getting back

```
\??\C:
```

I get back

```
\??\C:\฀\\?\C:
```

which is clearly incorrect?

---

Code snippet (in D):

```
struct CurDir { UnicodeString DosPath; HANDLE Handle; }

extern (Windows) static bool RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U(
    in const(wchar)* DosPathName, out UnicodeString NtPathName,
    out const(wchar)* NtFileNamePart, out CurDir DirectoryInfo);

wchar[] toNtPath(const(wchar)[] path)
{
    UnicodeString ntPath;
    CurDir curDir;
    const(wchar)* fileNamePart;
    enforce(RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U(path.ptr, ntPath,
        fileNamePart, curDir));
    try
    { return ntPath.Buffer[0 .. ntPath.Length / ntPath.Buffer[0].sizeof].dup; }
    finally { RtlFreeHeap(RtlGetProcessHeap(), 0, ntPath.Buffer); }
}

writeln(toNtPath(r"\\?\C:"));   //Returns the weird string
```

---

Update:

I figured out the problem -- see my answer.

Comment: What makes you think that API can handle such a path? And why are you calling that function? I can't find documentation for it.

Comment: @David: (1) Because what I'm giving it is a standard DOS path, and (2) because there's no other way I know of for me to translate an arbitrary DOS path into an NT path on Windows XP and later. Do you happen to know of a better function?

Comment: What is a DOS path? And where is that function documented?

Comment: @David: `\\?\C:` is a Win32 path (which is obviously called a DOS path too by Microsoft), whereas `\??\C:` is an NT-style path. And honestly, when there's no documented function to do what I need, I don't have a choice but to do something undocumented. If you have a documented solution to this, I'd be happy to hear it, but just telling me not to use it without giving me alternatives isn't very helpful. Also, take a look [here](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d8/dd5/ndk_2rtlfuncs_8h_a86dd854978cd372fdc21be85ec39c09c.html#a86dd854978cd372fdc21be85ec39c09c).

Comment: Where do DOS paths come into Windows programming? I'm curious.

Comment: @Hans That must be one of the options on the close dialog only available if rep>100k!!!

Comment: @Hans: Okay sorry, I'll post a snippet in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @David Heffernan: DOS paths use drive letters (e.g. `E:\a.txt`). NT paths refer to objects within the object manager (e.g. `\Device\HarddiskVolume3\a.txt`).

Comment: @David Heffernan: DOS paths come into play a lot with Windows programming. See [Naming Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), and look at `Short File Names` (a remnant of DOS), `Naming Conventions` (particularly the next to last bullet about reserved names, another DOS remnant), and `Namespaces`.

Comment: This is a rare discussion and very enlightening too...

Comment: To clarify, "\??\E:" is an NT path that uses the volume's persistent "E:" drive-letter name. We prefer this over non-persistsent, enumerated names such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume3", or whatever it happens to be for the moment. The user can remove the drive and reinsert it, and thus assign it a new name such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume9". Don't take the "DOS" as a stigma in "DosDevices". These are the well-known user-mode names for devices, whether you're using the Windows API with "\\.\" or "\\?\" or the NT API with "\??\".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself, with @wj32's help: I'd totally forgotten that the *input* to `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U` needed to be null-terminated, and my code didn't handle that properly. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 12):

`RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U` is giving you the correct output. The reason you see a weird-looking character in the middle is because `UNICODE_STRING`s are **not** required to be null-terminated (which I'm sure you know already). The file name `\??\C:\` is a completely valid native-format file name. I suspect what you really want is to prepend the device name instead of just referring to the `GLOBAL??` directory like what `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U` has done.

To do that, simply call `NtQuerySymbolicLinkObject` on `\??\x:`, where *x* is the drive letter that the path is using, and prepend the result. If it's a UNC path, prepend `\Device\Mup`. And so on for the other types of paths (if there are any).

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question! Unfortunately, I wasn't assuming that they're null-terminated -- I was using an array with the correct length. However, for some reason, after making a few changes I can't seem to reproduce the problem. I'll try to figure it out soon, but +1 thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the help, especially in the second paragraph. The UNC redirector seems to do what I need. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Then it's more likely you weren't dividing Length by 2.

Comment: Nope, I was doing that correct; I figured it out now! Thanks for the hint about null-termination -- see my answer! :)

Comment: Device names are often non-persistent. We should use the persistent mountpoints in "\??\". In XP+, "\??\" references the caller's local mountpoints (i.e. "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<Caller's Logon Session ID>"), which shadows the global mountpoints in "\Global??". (The SYSTEM logon is an exception that uses the global directory as its local directory.) The local directory also contains a "Global" link in case we need to get around local shadowing or to explicitly create a global mountpoint from a non-SYSTEM context.